# Is there a way to update a topic within a publication in Tridion Docs?

Tags: publishing, dynamic-publishing, tridion-docs

In our Tridion Docs implementation, we have topics that are used in multiple publications. And it would be really efficient, if we can only publish a topic to get the changes across all its referenced publications, instead of having to publish 1000s of such publications for changes in a single topic.
Is there a way to update a topic within a publication, without republishing the whole publication (i.e. by just publishing topic individually)?

Answer (score 1):

Which output format(s) are you publishing to? Are you trying to do this with Dynamic Delivery?

I have been looking into this question for some time. I have reviewed documentation, experimented with my demo environment, checked with DITA industry experts, as well as RWS representatives and SMEs. Unfortunately, there is no nice or easy out-of-the-box way to do this.

A couple approaches that I have brainstormed, but have not yet attempted:

1. There is a Publish button for individual topics in Tridion Docs, but I don't think it works with Dynamic Delivery. It outputs XML, for instance, and just copies it to the local file system and/or database, somewhere on the Docs CM server. I was trying to see where these get published to, but it's not straightforward to track it down. Anyway, the idea here would be to publish individual topics as XML, or maybe JSON or HTML, and then set up some kind of headless API to access the published content.
2. You could consider creating some kind of "wrapper" publication and map, that could potentially be used to publish individual topics . Seems like a tedious workaround, but could be an option, depending on the requirements.

Ultimately, an ideal solution would likely require some customization to the DITA-OT, publish plugins, etc. to make it work.